# Concatenate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have the following code in SQL

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select  MSISDN FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=' + @Path + ';HDR=YES', 'SELECT MSISDN FROM [sheet1$]')
```

i want  to concatenate the path in the database , but the concatenation isn't working , any idea ?

Comment: OPENROWSET is touchy - I believe (I'll have to double check) that you have to use string literals - no concatenating values.  One way to get around this is to concatenate the entire command in a string and then execute it (I've seen this done with sp_executesql).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a cursor?  Why not simply do a select via the `OPENROWSET`?

Comment: @Tim , i am using a cursor because i am comparing the table from excel to the current one in SQL , its working fine , but the problem is the path . About the concatenation , how do you think it should be done ?

Comment: I've posted an example of how to do the concatenation.  If you can post the rest of your SQL, chances are pretty good there is a better way to do your comparison than using a cursor.  Cursors have their time and place, but generally should not be used.  In my recent project I was able to get rid of all but one of several cursors and use set-based logic to accomplish what the cursor was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do string concatenation in `OPENROWSET` - the command expects string literals.  I recently had a project at work converting some old SQL that used OPENROWSET and ran into that issue.

One way around this is by using OPENROWSET to dump the data into a table variable, and then declare your cursor from the table variable.  Something like this (not tested):

```
DECLARE @data AS TABLE(MSISDN VARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT MSISDN FROM '
SET @sql = @sql + ' OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'','
SET @sql = @sql + '''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @Path + ';HDR=YES'','
SET @sql = @sql + '''SELECT MSISDN FROM [sheet1$]'')'

INSERT INTO @data
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT MSISDN FROM @data
```